# Error: Missing $ inserted in table of latex

Tags: tables

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Practically Used Deep CNN Networks}
\label{table1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
NET_WIT_DATASET  &  CNN_layer  &  in_a_network  &  combining_from_2_networks  &  combining_from_3_networks
\\ \hline \\
LeNet   MNIST            &  conv1       &  20       &   15      &   15 \\
LeNet MNIST            &  conv2     &  50       &  59       &   59 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10 &conv1      &24     &15     &16 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10 &conv2      &96     &107        &107 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

reported the error:

Missing $ inserted.

$
l.204 NET_
WIT_DATASET  & CNN_layer  &

Comment: Replace `_` with `\_`.

Comment: Unrelated but in order to avoid additional vertical white space, you might also want to replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`. Also a second orrucance of `\label` is not needed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you (a) encase the header strings that contain `_` (underscore) characters in `\url` directives to "neuter" the meaning of the special characters, (b) employ a `tabularx` environment to permit automatic line breaking in the final two columns, and (c) load the `xurl` package to permit line-breaking in URL strings at arbitrary points.

Incidentally, are these underscore characters really required? Can you maybe make do without them? If you can dispense with them, there would be no need for the `\url` wrappers, greatly simplifying the typesetting task.

Oh, if your document loads the `hyperref` package, you should change `\url` to `\nolinkurl` (since the strings aren't "real" URL strings...).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\urlstyle{same}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\caption{Practically Used Deep CNN Networks}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} llcCC @{}}
\toprule
\url{NET_WIT_DATASET}  &  
\url{CNN_layer}  &  
\url{in_a_network}  &  
\url{combining_from_2_networks}  &  
\url{combining_from_3_networks} \\ 
\midrule
LeNet MNIST     &  conv1    &  20   &  15   &  15 \\
LeNet MNIST     &  conv2    &  50   &  59   &  59 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10 &  conv1    &  24   &  15   &  16 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10 &  conv2    &  96   & 107   & 107 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```